# Page No pop up when scrolling the composite datawindow

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

Powerbuilder 12.0, Composite datawindow, whenever scrolling the report i am getting the Page number(Page 1, Page 2 ..) popup on the screen. How can we avoid this pop up ?

I am facing this issue in the Front end at run time. i am using powerbuilder classic version.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

based on my knowledge, that automatically  comes from vertical scroll bar of datawindow so it cannot turned off, better you send email request to Sybase(SAP) to include it in the next feature.

from pb developer